# bash: how to grep for a field and loop, appending results while field is in response

Tags: bash, nexus

I have a bash script which extracts some artifacts we have stored in a nexus repository using their REST api:

```
get_hosts()
{
    curl --silent -X GET "https://foo.bar/service/rest/v1/search?maven.groupId=foo.bar.hosts" |
        jq '.items[].name' --raw-output |
        sort -u
}

do_work()
{
    for host in $(get_hosts);
    do
        ...
    done
}
```

Recently this broke because the number of artifacts exceeded some threshold, and nexus uses [pagination](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/pagination)

> Many of the REST API's make use of a pagination strategy for dealing
> with operations that can return a large number of items. This strategy
> is built around the notion of a continuationToken and a page size that
> determines the maximum number of items that can be returned in a
> single response.

```
GET /service/rest/v1/<api>?<query>
```

> ```
> {
>   "items" : [
>     ...
>   ],
>   "continuationToken" : "88491cd1d185dd136f143f20c4e7d50c"
> }
> ```

```
GET /service/rest/v1/<api>?<query>&continuationToken=88491cd1d185dd136f143f20c4e7d50c
```

**Question:**

How can I modify my `get_hosts` function to grep for the `continuationToken`, and loop until all pages have been received?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this :

```
unset ct
get_hosts()
{
    res="$(curl -s "https://foo.bar/service/rest/v1/search?maven.groupId=foo.bar.hosts$ct" )"
    jq '.items[].name' --raw-output <<< "$res" | sort -u
    ct="&continuationToken=$(jq .continuationToken <<< "$res")"
}

do_work()
{
    while hosts="$(get_hosts)"; test -n "$hosts"
    do
        for host in $hosts;
        do
            ...
        done
    done
}
```